# AWS CDK typescript environment variable value validation

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I need to add `deployment_env` tag with possible value of `dev`, `test`, and `prod` on every resources deployed to AWS under a CDK stack, other than that all the resources should have same properties. I tried to use environment variable of `DEPLOYMENT_ENV` which is works fine, unless any value other than the possible value still go through and the CDK still can be synth-ed and deployed with any provided value. Not only that, when the environment variable isn't defined the typescript compiler doesn't validate the `undefined` or `null` value and error received upon value assignment to the tag of `Tag must have a value` which is expected to fail earlier. Here's the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import { App, Tags } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { EnvInitStack } from '../lib/foo-stack';

const deploymentEnv : 'dev' | 'test' | 'prod' = process.env.DEPLOYMENT_ENV as 'dev' | 'test' | 'prod';

const app = new App();
const fooStack = new FooStack(app, 'FooStack', {});

Tags.of(envInitStack).add('deployment_env', deploymentEnv as string);
```

1. using command `DEPLOYMENT_ENV=foo cdk synth` the cdk synth-ed and deployed successfully
2. using command `cdk synth` error received `Error: Tag must have a value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to verify your value 'deploymentEnv' value by js code not by type script defintion. try to add:

```
if (!['dev','test','prod'].includes(deploymentEnv))
    throw ('invalid deploymentEnv tag');
```

Comment: I do want to verify it by typescript definition but it doesn't work. any idea why is that?

Comment: you can't. process.env.ENV_NAME is only resolved at run time and in runtime there are no types...

Comment: that explains it all, thanks a lot for the explanation, explore a little bit and it seems like zod, io-ts, or runtypes is what I need to handle some runtime validation